# SkLearn : Odd Logistic Regression Correlation Coefficient ( Over 1 and lower -1 ) what is it?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

Calculating Correlations using SkLearn Logistic Regression gives a table where Correlation Coefficient's extreme values are lower -1 and over 1. I am not quite sure how do these Coefficients work, could you explain, please? Shouldn't they lay between -1 and 1, or I missing something?     [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSLHW.jpg)

Comment: No, that is not right. Coefficients in logistic regression can be any real number.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please post a question with code in it and not as a screenshot

Comment: Couldn't find how to mark an "Output" with the code option.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 types of predictions for `LogisticRegression` class:

- predict classess
- predict proba
- predict log proba.

It is in this third class you're getting your "strange" results.

See more for definitions on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression)

Comment: Thanks, Sergey. Now I get the concept. This video helped a lot to understand how Log function makes outputs of Odds and probabilities symmetrical for easier interpretation of Correlations.   And the dude sings funny too, lol :  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ARfXDSkQf1Y